# How can I find out what Change template a DOORS Module is using?

Tags: ibm-doors

I need to use DXL to loop through all modules in our database and find out which Rational Change Template each module is using, and possibly switch it to a different one. Can't find any documentation on Change API for DOORS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to contact IBM directly to get this information. But here it is if anyone else needs to do it.

```
Skip cfgData = createString
string current_template = ""

getModuleConfigurationData(m, cfgData)
find(cfgData, CSINT_CONFIG_USE_TEMPLATE, current_template)
delete cfgData
```

At this point `current_template` has the file name of the template that it is configured for. This can be used to compare to existing templates and verify it is set correctly.

Also, if an update is necessary the following function will save the skip list back to the configuration.

```
put(cfgData, CSINT_CONFIG_USE_TEMPLATE, new_template)
cmSaveModuleConfigurationData(m, cfgData)
```